# How to display specific data from firebase in recyclerview using it's child?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

For example, I'd like to display all orders that has fs_ID equal to FS02. I provided a screenshot of my firebase below:

[image: My firebase]

This is my current code:

```
public class NewOrders extends AppCompatActivity {

public RecyclerView recyclerView;
public RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;

FirebaseDatabase database;
DatabaseReference requests;

FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Request, OrderViewHolder> adapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_new_orders);

    //Firebase
    database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    requests = database.getReference("Order_Header");

    recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.listOrders);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

    adapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Request, OrderViewHolder>(
            Request.class,
            R.layout.order_layout,
            OrderViewHolder.class,
            requests.orderByChild("fs_ID")
                    .equalTo("FS02")
    ) {
        @Override
        protected void populateViewHolder(OrderViewHolder viewHolder, Request model, int position) {
            viewHolder.txtOrderID.setText(adapter.getRef(position).getKey());
            viewHolder.txtOrderStatus.setText(convertCodeToStatus(model.getStatus()));
            viewHolder.txtOrderUsername.setText(model.getUsername());
            viewHolder.txtOrderFname.setText(model.getFirstName());
            viewHolder.txtOrderLname.setText(model.getLastName());
            viewHolder.txtOrderEmail.setText(model.getEmail());
            viewHolder.txtOrderAddress.setText(model.getAddress());
        }
    };
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
}

private String convertCodeToStatus(String status){
    //pasok db how

    if (status.equals("OS1")) {
        return "Placed";
    }
    else if (status.equals("OS2")) {
        return "In progress";
    }
    else {
        return "OS3";
    }
}
```

}

The screen where it is suppose to show is empty, what might be the problem? Thanks

Comment: Hmm.... after writing an answer, I see that you're trying to query on a nested child. That is not possible with Firebase. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27207059/firebase-query-double-nested

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to not be calling `startListening` anywhere, which is required for FirebaseUI to start observing the database. Right now you told the `adapter` what data to observe, and what to do with it, but you never told it to start doing so.

You'll typically want to start listening in the `onStart` of your activity, and then stop listening in `onStop()`.

```
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    adapter.startListening();
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    adapter.stopListening();
}
```

Also see the [FirebaseUI documentation on the adapter lifecycle](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/master/database/README.md#firebaserecycleradapter-lifecycle).